# How Hadoop mapper works on the records which partially spills to next block?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to learn `MapReduce` in some detail, in particular the following query.

As we know that data in HDFS is broken into blocks and typically Mapper works on a block at a time; we can have the situation in which a `record` gets spilled to another block; for example:

Dataset:  "hello, how are \nyou doing"; this data might get spilled into two different blocks.

## Block1:

```
hello, how a
```

## Block2:

```
re  
you doing
```

Now, if Mapper works on Block1 , how does mapper get the "full" record from block1 which has spilled to Block2?

Could anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

It works on files, which could be stored on HDFS as more than one block. However, as far as the mapper is concered its working on a file and the blocks and where they split is irrelevant, it will just see the file and its complete contents.

Answer (score 1):

Block is physical division of data and InputSplit is a Logical division of data. 
**Input Split is how the recordReader presents the data to the mappers.**

When a data is stored there are chances of records being split across 2 blocks. InputSplit doesn’t contain actual data, but a reference to the data. InputSplit represents the data to be processed by an individual Mapper. Typically, it presents a byte-oriented view on the input and is the responsibility of RecordReader of the job to process this and present a record-oriented view. RecordReader, typically, converts the byte-oriented view of the input, provided by the InputSplit, and presents a record-oriented view for the Mapper and Reducer tasks for processing. It thus assumes the responsibility of processing record boundaries and presenting the tasks with keys and values.

How the data is splited depends upon InputFormat. Default InputFormat is FileInputFormat which uses lineFeed for InputSplit.

See also: [InputSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputSplit.html) 
and [RecordReader](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/RecordReader.html)